# Cross-platform benchmarking

Tags: windows, android, benchmarking

I am looking for a cross-platform benchmark tool. It must have versions for [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [windows](/questions/tagged/windows).

I would like standardized benchmarks across those two platforms.  Benchmarks are always somewhat subjective, so I won't make the requirements too strict.  For my purposes, the most important benchmarks, in order of importance are:

1. CPU throughput
2. Memory read/write speeds
3. GPU throughput

I *will* consider tools that do not have all those benchmarks.

Price must be [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis).  [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) is always preferred, but definitely *not* a requirement.